# Why isn't my Azure cost alert listed in the cost alert tab?

Tags: azure, azure-cost-management, azure-openai-service

I use Azure to call OpenAI models via Azure OpenAI Service. I created a resource. I created an instance assigned to that resource. I deployed a few OpenAI models in that instance. I created a budget for that instance. The budget contains a cost alert:

[image]

However, I don't see the cost alert in the cost alert tab:

[image]

Why isn't my Azure cost alert listed in the cost alert tab? If that's because a "budget alert" is different from a "cost alert", what's the difference?

I am confused because in the cost alert tab, if I click on "add", it only gives me the option to add a new budget (and I can add a budget cost alert while creating the new budget):

[image]

Comment: I am still interested in this question.

Comment: Any idea is welcome.